# How to print special characters in Prawn

Tags: pdf, prawn

Running Prawn 2.0.1.

Database contains the characters ntilde, aacute, and eacute.  These characters are in variable strings.  The font is Palatino Linotype.ttf. The text area is defined by:

```
pdf.column_box([0, pdf.cursor], columns => 1, :width =>pdf.bounds.width, :align => :justify) do pdf.text generation_text, :inline_format => true
end
```

Currently the characters do not print and the character space is missing, as if the character is not there.  How do you get these characters to print?

Comment: you meant other characters are displayed but just not these 3 words?

Comment: Those are not words but the name of characters.  This problem is a non problem because it was discovered that the characters were stripped on input to the database, therefore it is not a Prawn issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there was no problem with Prawn

See OP's comment:
Those are not words but the name of characters. This problem is a non problem because it was discovered that the characters were stripped on input to the database, therefore it is not a Prawn issue.